# How to delay local NFS changes for eternity

Tags: nfs

I have a situation where I want to share a filesystem on the network. I want the filesystem to be writable on clients that the filesystem is shared to, but I don't want the changes propagated back to the server, ever. You could think of this file share as a way to "warm a cache" on clients. Is there a way to specify that a file share is writable, but the updates from clients should be delayed forever? Maybe declare it a read only file share, but remount it with `rw` filesystem options on the client?  I'm mentioning NFS specifically as my company uses it for other file sharing chores.

Comment: Why not just mount, copy it locally, unmount? Otherwise you'll need some odd kind of CoW system I think...

Comment: Yeah, that sounds much simpler, and the intent probably more obvious to people who happen upon the thing in the wild. Thanks.